# a very ill conditioned linear system

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a linear system to solve, written as Ax=b
A is a 175 by 175 symmetric square, with ones at it's diagonal (i.e., aii=1), and other entries ranges from 0 to 1(i.e., 0

A is very ill conditioned, and not positive definite, its rank is 162 and its condition number is 3.5869e+16

I spent several days to solve this in MATLAB, I've tried almost every method I can find, including \, pcg, bicg, bicgstab, bicgstabl, cgs, gmres, lsqr, minres, qmr, symmlq, tfqmr
These methods gave me some solutions. But I don't know how to trust them, or which solution to trust. Is there a criteria to determine?

I'll appreciate someone who can give me a solution that I can trust.
Thanks!

A and b are stored in .mat files and can be download from dropbox links:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6xlbq68juqs6xi/A.mat?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxl0hdup20hf2lr/b.mat?dl=0

use like this:

load('A.mat');

load('b.mat');

x = A\b;

Comment: Can you not express the problem with another linear system that is better conditioned?

Comment: Do you expect there to be a unique solution, even though `A` is not full rank? If not, are you looking to find a solution with minimum mean square error? Have you tried looking at the results of `(A*x-b)'*(A*x-b)` to see if the error is satisfactory?

Comment: @eigenchris Thanks for reply. I'm looking to find a solution with minumum mean square error. How small is (A*x-b)'*(A*x-b) regarded as satisfactory? Is 1e-07 small enough?

Comment: @happycharleswang With an error of `1e-07`, it sounds like `A*x` does a pretty good job of reconstructing `b`, so I wouldn't worry about it. In general, whether the error is "small enough" ultimately depends on you and what you need for your application.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for reply. That's a good point! I'll check that.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for answer. Not very familiar with that, but I'll try that.

Comment: @eigenchris Thanks. Among all methods, A\b gives the smallest residual  (Ax-b)'*(Ax-b)~1e-23. Others give about 1e-7. However, I doubt A\b. If x=A\b, I notice some abs of entries of x are very large, and this is not supposed  to happen because it conflicts with the physical phenomenon I  am simulating. I am expecting all entries of the solution x should be >= 0 and <=1. All solvers except A\b satisfy my expectation, although they don't have the smallest residual. Seems wired? what happened to A\b? And can I trust A\b?

Comment: The `x=A\b` solution calculates the least-squared-error solution, which minimizes `||Ax-b||^2`. It was smart of you to check `abs(x)`--if some entries are unacceptably large, this can be fixed by using the "regularization" technique suggested by Ander. Regularization "punishes" values of `x` that are too large and forces the entries of `x` to remain small. As mentioned, the Gamma matrix can be the identity, but it may be something you need to tune, perhaps multiplying by a constant. Regularization isn't an exact science and requires intuition and playing around with the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @eigenchris! regularization is the solution I want!

Comment: @eigenchris Exactly! To be a bit picky, Tikhonov regulazitaion with an identity matrix punishes big values of `x`. Some other regularization techniques will punish some other properties, as total variation for example! But indeed, damn regularization!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, a good point: I was referring to the Tikhonov/L2 regularization in your post. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but give it a go:

[**Tikhonov regularization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)

Basically, when the following is hard to compute due to ill-conditiones:

[image]

You minimize the following instead

[image]

Being \Gamma generally the identity matrix.

In the end, you get the following equation for x:

[image]

To add to that, you will generally want to add an "hyperparameter", to control how much you regularize the problem. So \Gamma instead of being just the identity matrix, it will be a number (i.e. 0.001) multiplied by the identity matrix of `size(A)`.

The last equation should be straightforward to try in Matlab. Give it a go.

**NOTE:** this is not *the answer*. Actually probably there is no unique answer to solving an ill posed problem. This is just a way to go.

Comment: As you noted, regularization, as used here, is a trick to improve the original system's conditioning. The solution to the new problem is not guaranted to have more meaning than the ones obtained by solving the original least-squares problem numerically.

Comment: @Jubobs Indeed! I haven't tested the OP's matrices, but when I use this method with mine, the least squares problem can not be solved due to floating point arithmetic limits. Thus, this is the way to go. This is a trick to use when `x=A\b` will just not work.

Comment: You do manage to solve *some* system, but you have to ask yourself: is this new system (and its solution) even related to the original problem? If the original system is not well conditioned, I would go back to where I got it and try to reformulate the problem in order to get a better-conditioned system.

Comment: @Jubobs Indeed! But One thing is having an ill-conditioned matrix created by a poor description of the real system (e.g. poor FEM quality), but, some other times you have a ill-posed system, where the nature and physics of the system are like that by default. If you want an example, I do electrical impedance tomography (EIT), where the only possible solution is by regularization (in tomography in general). I dont know what the OP has, but indeed both cases need to be considered.

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri and jubobs and eigenchris, Tikhonov regularization is the solution I want. You guys made my day!